# Creating a single trigger for Insert/Update/Delete in SQL with Two Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I Need to create a Single Trigger From   First_DataBase TableA  to Second_DataBase TableB

When ever any modification done on TableA it'll affect the TableB

In this concept i am using Two DataBase

Whenever a row is inserted or updated or deleted in Table A, it should be affect the Table B.

Same Columns Name for TableA and TableB

How to handle this from a single trigger?

Comment: first of all know the purpose of triggers.In most cases triggers used for backup for main transaction table.then why you required in two databases @shreeharini

Comment: In my case I am taking the backup to another database  for the security purpose @mohan111

Comment: It really isn't any different than any other trigger. It sounds like nothing more than standard CRUD operations between two tables. I would NOT try to do this in a single trigger. I would create three triggers. Separate ones for UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE. Better yet would be a find an alternative and not use any triggers but I don't know your process or what you are trying to do.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?  This seems pretty standard for a trigger.

Comment: for better understanding go through this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Update-and-Delete-Triggers-in-SQL-Server-with-example.aspx

Comment: why not just use replication for something like this?  If you're going to communicate ALL changes for ALL tables, it seems like ***huge*** overhead to write RUD triggers for each and every table

Comment: and what do you mean by "In my case I am taking the backup to another database for the security purpose"?  If you're reflecting all changes to all tables, then the two tables from db1 and db2 will always be equal... how is this secure?

Comment: There is nothing special about handling it in a trigger.   Are you getting an error when you try?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a linked server between database a and b (with permission allowing for inserts on the second) you can create a trigger that updates both tables (you have to refer to the second table on the linked server using the linked server name to refer to it).

Comment: Note that OP did state "two databases", not "two database servers" though I guess it is a decent guess since otherwise the question just sounds like a normal trigger

Comment: Ya its not a two "database servers"  its "two databases"   In this concept DataBaseA having 40 tables, Just i am creating a New Database as DataBaseB, I am going to copy all the 40 tables from DataBaseA to DataBaseB and i am renaming the 40 Tables, After that i am going to Use Trigger Concept for INSERT\UPDATE\DELETE, and Whenever a row is inserted or updated or deleted in Table A (DataBaseA) , it should be affect the Table B(DataBaseB) ...... Any body having Idea how to do this?

Comment: If you use a 3 part name you can update the data in other database.

Comment: can you explain with example

Comment: @ShreeHarini [databaseName].[schemaName].[tableName]